# How to show breadcrumb with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJS.
How can I show breadcrumbs dynamically with Angularjs?

My url is: `http://localhost/letsTravel/#/our-offer`,
so my breadcrumb should show **'Our offer**'.

If url is: `http://localhost/letsTravel/#/`,
breadcrumbs should be hidden.

Html for breadcrumb is inside header tag:

```
<header>
      <div>
         <nav class="breadcrumbs" ng-controller="breadcrumController" >  
            <a href="#/" >Home</a> &rarr;
            <span>Our offer</span>
         </nav>
       </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: You can dynamically display or hide your breadcrumb with the `ng-if` or `ng-show` directives. The `$location` service which you probably already use for the breadcrumb's content will tell you whether or not you are at the context root.

Comment: @Aaron `app.controller('BreadcrumCtrl',function($location,$scope){
 console.log($location);
 $scope.path=$location.$$path;
 
});`
`<nav class="breadcrumbs" ng-controller="BreadcrumCtrl" >
      <a href="#/" >Home</a> &rarr;
      <span>{{path}}</span>
     </nav>`
i am using the above code. but when my url changes the **"$location.$$path"** the **{{path}}** remains the same. it changes when i reload the page

Comment: @Aaron can you please guide me how to change the name in breadcrum dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice article how to use breadcrumbs http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/100/auto-breadcrumbs-with-angular-ui-router